# How to split big numbers?

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have a big number, which I need to split into smaller numbers in Python. I wrote the following code to swap between the two:

```
def split_number (num, part_size):
    string = str(num)
    string_size = len(string)

    arr = []
    pointer = 0 
    while pointer < string_size:
        e = pointer + part_size
        arr.append(int(string[pointer:e]))
        pointer += part_size
    return arr 

def join_number(arr):
    num = ""
    for x in arr:
        num += str(x)
    return int(num)
```

But the number comes back different. It's hard to debug because the number is so large so before I go into that I thought I would post it here to see if there is a better way to do it or whether I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, any leading `0`s in the "parts" can't be preserved by this operation.  Can't `join_number` also receive the `part_size` argument, so that it can reconstruct the string formats with all the leading zeros?

Without some information such as `part_size` that's known to both the sender and receiver, or the equivalent (such as the base number to use for a similar split and join based on arithmetic, roughly equivalent to `10**part_size` given the way you're using `part_size`), the task becomes quite a bit harder.  If the receiver is initially clueless about this, why not just place the `part_size` (or base, etc) as the very first int in the `arr` list that's being sent and received?  That way, the encoding trivially becomes "self-sufficient", i.e., doesn't need any supplementary parameter known to both sender and receiver.

Comment: Ahh, leading zeroes, of course. It is possible to make the first integer in the array the part_size.

Thanks a lot for your help, I don't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to convert to and from strings, which can be very time consuming for really large numbers

```
>>> def split_number(n, part_size):
...     base = 10**part_size
...     L = []
...     while n:
...         n,part = divmod(n,base)
...         L.append(part)
...     return L[::-1]
... 
>>> def join_number(L, part_size):
...     base = 10**part_size
...     n = 0
...     L = L[::-1]
...     while L:
...         n = n*base+L.pop()
...     return n
... 
>>> print split_number(1000005,3)
[1, 0, 5]
>>> print join_number([1,0,5],3)
1000005
>>>
```

Here you can see that just converting the number to a `str` takes longer than my entire function!

```
>>> from time import time
>>> t=time();b = split_number(2**100000,3000);print time()-t
0.204252004623
>>> t=time();b = split_number(2**100000,30);print time()-t
0.486856222153    
>>> t=time();b = str(2**100000);print time()-t
0.730905056
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think of the following number split into 3-sized chunks:

```
1000005 -> 100 000 5
```

You have two problems. The first is that if you put those *integers* back together, you'll get:

```
100 0 5 -> 100005
```

(i.e., the middle one is 0, not 000) which is not what you started with. Second problem is that you're not sure what size the last part should be.

I would ensure that you're first using a string whose length is an exact multiple of the part size so you know *exactly* how big each part should be:

```
def split_number (num, part_size):
    string = str(num)
    string_size = len(string)
    while string_size % part_size != 0:
        string = "0%s"%(string)
        string_size = string_size + 1

    arr = []
    pointer = 0
    while pointer < string_size:
        e = pointer + part_size
        arr.append(int(string[pointer:e]))
        pointer += part_size
    return arr
```

Secondly, make sure that you put the parts back together with the right length for each part (ensuring you don't put leading zeros on the first part of course):

```
def join_number(arr, part_size):
    fmt_str = "%%s%%0%dd"%(part_size)
    num = arr[0]
    for x in arr[1:]:
        num = fmt_str%(num,int(x))
    return int(num)
```

Tying it all together, the following complete program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def split_number (num, part_size):
    string = str(num)
    string_size = len(string)
    while string_size % part_size != 0:
        string = "0%s"%(string)
        string_size = string_size + 1

    arr = []
    pointer = 0
    while pointer < string_size:
        e = pointer + part_size
        arr.append(int(string[pointer:e]))
        pointer += part_size
    return arr

def join_number(arr, part_size):
    fmt_str = "%%s%%0%dd"%(part_size)
    num = arr[0]
    for x in arr[1:]:
        num = fmt_str%(num,int(x))
    return int(num)

x = 1000005
print x
y = split_number(x,3)
print y
z = join_number(y,3)
print z
```

produces the output:

```
1000005
[1, 0, 5]
1000005
```

which shows that it goes back together.

Just keep in mind I haven't done Python for a few years. There's almost certainly a more "Pythonic" way to do it with those new-fangled lambdas and things (or whatever Python calls them) but, since your code was of the basic form, I just answered with the minimal changes required to get it working. Oh yeah, and be wary of negative numbers :-)

Comment: num = `'%s%*d' % (num, part_size, int(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for Alex Martelli's answer.

```
def digits(n, base):
    while n:
        yield n % base
        n //= base

def split_number(n, part_size):
    base = 10 ** part_size
    return list(digits(n, base))

def join_number(digits, part_size):
    base = 10 ** part_size
    return sum(d * (base ** i) for i, d in enumerate(digits))
```