# String To Int For BigInt Manual Conversion

Tags: string, c++11, int

I have a problem with converting string to int, need to save a 5 digit number in each std::list element. I use this:

```
for(int i =0; i< e.length(); ++i)
{
    tmp = tmp*10+ e[i] - '0';
    ++rads;
    if(rads>4) 
    {
       numbs.push_back(tmp);
       rads=0;
       tmp=0;
    }
}
```

If in input number is:

> 10000 00012 02345 00001

in list I will get:

> 10000    12  2345     1

All the problem is to save without loosing zeros after

> rads>4 or rads==Rads

What I also tried:

> To save as base #define-d Rads

```
for(int i =0; i< e.length(); ++i)
{
    tmp = tmp*10+ e[i] - '0';
    if(tmp>=Rads) // Rads defined as 10000
    {
       cumul = cumul*10+tmp/Rads;
       tmp = tmp%Rads;
    }
   if(cumul>=Rads) // Rads defined as 10000
    {
       numbs.push_back(cumul);
       cumul = 0;
    }

}
```

I've read and looked into various sources codes and articles related to this, in none of them there was suitable solution (not code, but idea at least) or solution was to save as int/char [by one digit]. By one is the easiest way, but it will be too expensive to process one int with only 2^4 bits occupied. That's why I am looking for the way to save 5 digit integer in x32 word, so it could be possible to fit working time limits and avoid rewriting of already realized code for "+ - / * %"
In search more or less close question posted close to mine was [How to split big numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394698/how-to-split-big-numbers/2394788#2394788)

Comment: Numbers never have leading zeroes. You only add leading zeros when printing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like I have to accept challenge and work on harder algo for plus, minus, mul and div.
For now input goes like this:

```
 unsigned int tmp = 0, cumul = 0, rads = 0;
    for(int i =0; i< e.length(); ++i)
    {
        tmp = tmp*10+e[i]-'0';
        if(tmp>=10000)
        {
            numbs.push_back(tmp);
            tmp =0;
        }
        else if(!tmp)
        {
            while(rads<5 && e[i]=='0')
            {
                ++rads; ++i;
            }
            --i;                                        //decrement following main loop increment
            numbs.push_back(ZBit+rads); // rads hold number of zeros after first 
                                                        //occurence
            //cout<<"Processed "<<rads<<" zeros"<<endl;
            rads = 0;
        }
    }
    if(tmp>0){numbs.push_back(tmp);}
```

And output:

```
list<unsigned int>::iterator it= numbs.begin();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<numbs.size(); i++)
    {
         if(*it>ZBit)
         {
             while(*it>ZBit)
             {
                 *it = *it - 1;
                 cout<<'0';
                     }
         }
        else{cout<<*it;}
            ++it;
    }
```

Now it saves 2-5 zeros as ZBit+rads in each *it, have no idea how to realize arithmetic on such a container.

Answer (score 2):

"Leading zeroes" are a property of how you render numbers for human viewing (i.e. a string that contains digit characters). They are not inherent to the value itself.

Consequently, the leading zeroes don't actually exist.

You can add leading zeroes to your eventual output if you wish.

Comment: You are talking about what is "obvious". I am splitting long string . size()>18 into 5 digit int, where I can't find the way to save it and use for arithmetic ops for fixed size of each element of list<unsigned int>

Comment: @EpiGen: Sorry, I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: Then why did you post "answer" instead of "comment"? Do you know any programmer that does not know that in any given integer be it written  on paper or in code "Leading zeroes" are meaningless???

Comment: @EpiGen: I answered the question. Then, you commented on it. Unfortunately, I did not understand your comment whatsoever. And as for your latest question, yes, I see that confusion on Stack Overflow every week. Your question exhibits that confusion. If you do in fact understand leading zeroes, then you should make your question clearer because right now that's not how it looks.

Comment: There was:" If in input number is:

`10000 00012 02345 00001`

in list I will get:

`10000 12 2345 1`  Isn't it clear enough from this?

Comment: No, not really. You still haven't explained what you _want_ to happen.